# How can i fix this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' (This is a tip calculator)

Tags: python-3.x

My code is here:

```py
import sys
from tkinter import *
def mhello():
    text1 = total
    mlabel1 = Label(text=text1, fg ="red")
    mlabel1.pack()
    return
dog = Tk()
input0 = StringVar()
input1 = StringVar()
input2 = StringVar()
dog.geometry('450x450')
dog.title("Tip Calculator")
mlabel = Label(text='This is a Simple Tip Calculator', fg ="red")
mlabel.pack()
mentry = Entry(dog, textvariable=input0)
mentry.pack()
mentry0 = Entry(dog, textvariable=input1)
mentry0.pack()
mentry1 = Entry(dog, textvariable=input2)
mentry1.pack()
meal = input0.get()
tax = input1.get()
tip = input2.get()
tip = tip / 100
tax = tax / 100
meal = meal + meal * tax
total = meal + meal * tip
mbutton = Button(text='Calculate',command = mhello)
mbutton.pack()

dog.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hint: What do you think `StringVar` is for?

Comment: Please show some research effort before straight-asking for code

Comment: @heltonbiker: Yes, since OP just posted a link to Google Docs document, while this site is meant to aim for self-contained questions & answers (otherwise it would easily be outdated). Did I break anything?

Answer (score 0):

Input.get() returns string, you have to convert it to float: float(Input0.get())

Comment: Nvm now I get this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 0):

You cannot divide string by integer. Instead first convert it to `int` or `float`, depending on your goal:

```py
>>> '120' / 100

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    '120' / 100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
>>> int('120') / 100
1
>>> float('120') / 100
1.2
```

In your case this piece:

```py
meal = input0.get()
tax = input1.get()
tip = input2.get()
```

should be replaced with:

```py
meal = float(input0.get())
tax = float(input1.get())
tip = float(input2.get())
```

Comment: Oh ok I was trying to get the input and then convert it to a float but still got errors this is what I needed thanks. :)

Comment: Nvm I get this error now: ValueError: could not convert string to float: